# What is the meaning of "but" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

Now, researchers from the Hanns-Christoph Nägerl Institute for Experimental Physics of the University of Innsbruck, Austria have observed a system of quantum particles tunnel through five potential barriers, *succeeding where but one particle could not*.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it as "only", so "succeeding where only one particle could not".